# Understanding INKEY$ in ZX BASIC

Tags: zx-spectrum, basic

The ZX BASIC Manual gives the [following little program to demonstrate how INKEY$](http://www.worldofspectrum.org/ZXBasicManual/zxmanchap18.html) works:

```
10 IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN GO TO 10 
20 IF INKEY$ = "" THEN GO TO 20 
30 PRINT INKEY$; 
40 GO TO 10
```

While I have ascertained that this works, and that if you remove line 10 (as the manual goes on to suggest), you get several letters displayed per keypress, I just don't understand the logic of it. I mean, `IF INKEY$ <> ""` and `IF INKEY$ = ""` would seem to cover all logical possibilities. How does the program ever get to line 30?

So my question is: **What exactly is the logic of `INKEY$`f in ZX BASIC, and why do these two conditions not produce an inescapable loop?**

Comment: Ugh, a thousand memories have just returned of when not being able to receive multiple keypresses was the thing that destroyed many an attempted game in BASIC.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Well spotted: I didn't have the benefit of the Sinclair keyboard there :-D

Comment: Get one, they still show up on flea markets and online sites for low money - today often with a realy impressive collection of additional hardware and books. You need to feel the real thing.

Comment: @Raffzahn I do have a real working rubber-keyed ZX Spectrum and a ZX81 (not to mention a German-keyboard Epson HX-20 which I bought on a flea market in Berlin), but my original typo came from re-typing the Speccy code on my modern keyboard, so without the benefit of BASIC keyboard tokens :-)

Comment: @Raffzahn I agree there's nothing like the real thing!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Some comprehensive BASIC to start with

There are BASICly three (*1) kinds of statements to handle single keystrokes in various BASICs (*2):

1. Waiting for a single keyvalue to arrive and returning it.
2. Checking if a key has been pressed, if yes, it's read and returned, otherwise an empty value is returned
3. Delivering the actual state of the (decoded) keyboard without any waiting or checking.

Most classic BASICs follow version #1 or #2, as they work with keystroke buffers like when there is a terminal connection. Many homecomputer BASICs, especially of the Microsoft kind follow #2, while mainframe BASICs often follow #1. Usually, but not always, it is called `GET` (*3). #3 is common among 'creative' BASICs that support game programming, including Sinclair BASIC.

### All three have their reasoning:

**Version #1** stops the program run until a keypress is received, thus waiting for it does not need to do any further handling. Convenient on more text and business style application - also, in a mainframe environment, input is sometimes only available in blocking versions

**Version #2** is about as low level as any terminal based system can get. It only peeks into the input buffer, but if there is a character, it gets extracted and delivered. This allows more interactivity, but still can only report *'no keypress'* or *'this key has been pressed and released'* (*4).

**Version #3** now is something that can only be accomplished if the keyboard state is in direct access to the BASIC interpreter. It delivers this state each time called. So handling input is much like on Assembly programs. There is no filter about pressing or releasing. This has to be done by the BASIC program. As a result, each and every key (*5) behaves much like a joystick switch. Not only pressing, but also exact timing of press and release can be detected - thus including duration of press.

### In practice this translates to three different logics:

**Version #1** is the most relaxed, as it always returns with a key pressed.

**Version #2** also returns when no key is pressed, so if waiting is required, it needs to be looped around. Of course, other things can be done during that loop before checking the keyboard again.

**Version #3** does need edge discrimination (*6) when used, differentiating key press and key release to form a keystroke if this is the goal.

### Now for your question

> What exactly is the logic of INKEY$ in ZX BASIC,

Sinclair BASIC's `INKEY$` follows Version #3 and delivers just the actual state. Perfect for timing relevant game programming, but a bit more work for the programmer of more mundane tasks.

In your example it works like this:

```
10 IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN GO TO 10
```

This loop waits until **no** key is pressed by reading the matrix over and over again

```
20 IF INKEY$ = "" THEN GO TO 20
```

This loop waits until **a** key is pressed by reading the matrix over and over again

```
30 PRINT INKEY$;
```

Now the matrix gets read one more time and the result is displayed.

> and why do these two conditions not produce an inescapable loop?

Because it's always checking the actual state, not some buffer. The logic is the one of an edge discriminator (*6), not so much of an OS call as modern languages offer.

But yes, there is a chance to screw it, if you're able to press and release faster than thee lines are executed may result, depending on your timing, in lost keystrokes, missed keystrokes or wrong returned. Then again, We are talking about a human operation the membrane here. Fat chance :))

A truly secure routine would be a bit slower, a bit more complex and look like this:

```
10 A$ = INKEY$
20 IF A$ = "" THEN GO TO 10
30 IF INKEY$ <> "" THEN GO TO 30
40 PRINT A$
50 GO TO 10
```

Now we read the keyvalue only once and store it for later processing. This will always record the first key pressed, no matter if later on others got pressed (before releasing all).

---

*1 - Make that 6, as some BASICs define `INKEY` as numeric, while others (like Sinclair) made it string based.

*2 - It's `INKEY` on Sinclair, `GET` on Microsoft, and maybe other names on lesser known dialects. I just use `INKEY` for the remaining answer to simplify wording. I'm well aware the Sinclair might have chosen INKEY instead of GET to make clear that here a different behaviour is to be expected.

*3 - None of these single key reading operations where part of the [original Dartmouth BASIC](http://www.dartmouth.edu/basicfifty/commands.html) (as FORTRAN didn't offer anything about keystrokes), thus names are made up by each implementation in their own way.

*4 - Usually it's reported the time it is pressed, but both ways have been used.

*5 - Depending on the keyboard structure and scanning, multiple key combinations may or may not work.

*6 - An edge discriminator in electronics is a circuit to detect when a signal changes, like detecting a rising or falling flank (aka edge), for example in interrupt handling or alinke. Here it describes a procedural way to detect when a condition changes - from not pressed to pressend, and back.

Comment: Don't want to nitpick too much but I don't remember seeing an INKEY$ that did option 1. GET usually paused and INKEY returned immediately (BBC Micro follows this rule) MS Basics usually used INKEY$ (certainly any that used GET for file IO did). The only exceptions would be commodore basics that didn't wait. Atari basic seems even weirder

Comment: @PeterI Applesoft (a MS-BASIC) did use GET and did not wait. The whole behaviour of GET/INKEY/whatsoeveritsnamed is machine/BASIC specific, as it is a leter addition. Same for the name. There is no well defined rules what name will cause what behaviour. For #1, there is for example a /370 BASIC close based on the original Dartmouth BASIC but offering a waiting GET (for reading terminal function keys)

Comment: @Raffzahn GET on AppleSoft did indeed wait, but only for one keypress. The Apple II did not have a function like INKEY$ (return character if pressed or empty if none), but could be simulated in AppleSoft by testing PEEK(-16384)>127. If true, then a key was pending. Retrieve it either by a GET command or use that PEEK value and then POKE a value into -16353 to clear the keyboard strobe. Obviously the GET would be a touch easier :-)

Comment: @bjb Details are well known. I still got my straight II ;) This Q is about the BASIC instructions, not so much machine specific hacks to circumfence it. Isn't it?

Comment: @Raffzahn I was referring to your comment to Peterl where you state "Applesoft did use GET and did not wait", not the general answer. Unless one of us misunderstood the other? ;-)

Comment: @bjb you're right. Mixed that up.

Comment: Yep I hit enter too early and it's a badly phrased comment (and I was torn over deleting it).

Comment: Well, we could go ahead and delete all of them at three ...1 ...2 ...

Comment: All the answers answered my question clearly, but this one went the extra mile in explaining the underlying logic, so it's the one I've accepted. I took the liberty of tidying up the spelling/typos, hope that's OK.

Comment: @harlandski I'm well aware that my English is less than perfect - not to mention rather random spelling - so I'm realy grateful for any help ironing them out. Thanks. Hans

Comment: I'm not a ZX user, but I can imagine that without line 10 (in the OP's program), INKEY$ would be the character value of ENTER, the same key that has been pressed when starting the program (RUN, then ENTER). So line 10 basically means "wait for the ENTER key to be released".

Comment: @Raffzahn Viel besser als mein geschriebenes Deutsch :-D

Comment: What’s the difference between “lost keystrokes” and “missed keystrokes”?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Hey, there is someone realy reading it :)) There are 3 INKEY statements with the original programm. A lost keystroke is one that has been detected by the second as made, but not read (and printed) by the third, because the key has been released inbetween. A missed one is one that got pressed and released while looping around INKEY #1 without noticing it, and a wrong one is where between #2 and 3 a new has been made. As said, chances are slim, but possible, as BASIC isn't fast either.

Comment: @Raffzahn Great explanation, but there's a subtle difference between the original and your amended version of the code. The first waits until no key is pressed, then returns the _next_ key pressed (something similar is often done to consume any keys that might be in a "type-ahead buffer" so a critical question isn't answered by a random earlier key-press). Your version will return the key _already being pressed_ (after waiting for it to be released).

Comment: @TripeHound yes. Thats right. And on purpose, as it reduces possible timing issues if there is a lot of processing before the next `INKEY` is due. While it isn't a real type ahead buffer, it at least chatches a key already pressed. A difference only occures at the very beginning of a programm run - which can be handles (if needed) byone waiting loop right at the start. As usual, one can find arguments for either way to handle it, and whatever suits a task depends thereon. I found this quite useful in real world szenarios. YMMV.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant as a criticism,  it was just to highlight that the two versions did slightly different things.

Comment: @TripeHound I took it exactly as that, positive critique. I love it if people look close at y posts and find remarkable parts.

Comment: Also it's worth noting that this code is a "leading edge detector" since line 30 is reached when the keystroke is detected. You could add `A$ = INKEY$` after this line, then another loop waiting for the trailing edge (repeat the line 10 loop). This would detect both the press and release of the key and store it in A$

Answer (score 23):

I suspect your confusion is because INKEY$ returns the current state of the keyboard, not a buffered stream of up / down key presses (On serial terminal based systems such as CP/M you'd get the character code which might have buffer depending on the hardware).

Basically the code could be written:

10 Wait for all keys to be up.

20 Wait for a key to be pressed

30 Print pressed key

40 back to start again.

Comment: A buffered up/down stream is something _very_ PC specific. Before the PC, there where only character buffers.

Comment: Your very right, buffered up down seems to be a PC invention (and you just sent me off on a wild goose chase when I remembered the QL 8049)

Comment: @PeterI not an invention but necessity due to way PC (screwy) keyboard is interconnected to PC ... PC does not have access to the matrix it only receives key up/down messages ... and only for keys stored in keyboard buffer which was usually i8048 with 128Byte RAM for everything (including registers and stack)

Comment: Same is true for the QL (well mostly you can scan rows individually) and lots of other machines Apple // and Atari 400/800 spring to mind. All of these tend to provide a single keystroke rather than access to the keyboard matrix scan. QL uses an 8049, Apple a keyboard chip (signetics?) and the Atari is the Pokey

Answer (score 10):

Lines 10 and 20 do cover all possibilities, but they don't cover them at the same time.

Line 10 is saying, "do not proceed to the next line as long as there's still a key being pressed from before."

Line 20 is saying, "now that no key is being pressed, stay here until one is being pressed."

You will reach line 30 only when you first press a key, which it will print, then it will go back to line 10 to wait for you to release that key, then on to line 20 to wait for you to press a new one.

Answer (score 2):

Inkey$ is read each time it is used, as such could be different each time in the if equation.

The line 10 and 20 combination is latch.

This combination was used rather than the Input command which stop the program and waited foe a user responce.  This latched inkey$ method allows some program to keep running while a user can input and control.

The problem I used to find with Inkey$ is that the longer the basic program was the slower it scanned Inkey$, and the latch would get sloppy and misread, even with the A$ storage method.

So programmers put the Inkey$ latch <> = into a Def Fn command and called it via Function, which helped the scan sloppyness, but at a cost of the Def Fn taking up some of the memory so less lengthy basic programs.

Another way was to make the Inkey$ latch <> = into machine code and called the check via say Command  USR 60000 and then used the result = A$ and used that.   Ie making a new command ie Stick or keyboard, which was better than using command Input.

They are alot of hacks to the Input command, you can use it like the Echo command in DOS and use it not for user entry but like the Print command or goto or call machine code and If to itself again to stop break command being used and the User hack crashing a machine code program to basic.

Some program used Inkey$ USR to call machine code so if inkey$ every got to call a check then the machine would crash rather than letting the user default back to Basic and hacking or Saving the program.

The Def FN and USR commands are quite powerful in Sinclair Basic and can do more than designed to do by doing weird equations.   So one actually did chess in Basic in one line using Def FN command.

Answer (score 1):

Raffzahn's answer is excellent and deserves to be the accepted answer but I would like to add another viewpoint.

It only appears to be impossible for the program to get to line 30 because of an implicit expectation that INKEY$ will return the same value on successive calls.  However, if this was the case then one of line 10 or 20 by itself would block.  Understanding why that is not the case requires a realisation that successive calls to INKEY$ might return different values.  Once this is understood, the apparent impossibility should evaporate.

In some languages, a declaration of a function allows the specification of "deterministic" or "non-deterministic".  When I first saw this, my reaction was: "Of course it is deterministic, it's a computer program".  However, both cases are possible.  A sensibly implemented sqrt or log function will be deterministic.  You would not expect multiple calls to sqrt(2) to return different values.  However, you should not be surprised if time() or rand() return different values.  INKEY$ is of the latter type: non-deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, INKEY$ is not a variable (though it looks like one) but a **function call**.  The logic of the program is as follows:

```
1: While any key is pressed, wait.
2: While no key is pressed, wait.
3: Print the key that is currently pressed.
4: Go back to step 1.
```

If you eliminate step 1, then whenever you have a key pressed, step 2 will immediately terminate, and proceed to step 3, and this tight loop will repeat continuously - until you release the key, when step 2 becomes effective again.